# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, file, parsing, substring

Code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < rate.length; i++){
                if(i == 0 | i == 4 | i == 8 | i == 12 | i == 18 | i == 22 | i == 26 | 
                        i == 30 | i == 34){
                    System.out.println(rate[i]);
                    String parsedRate = rate[i].substring(0, 5);
                    System.out.println(parsedRate);
                    double rt = Double.parseDouble(parsedRate);
                    if(rt > max){
                        max = rt;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Output:

10.00%
10.00

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at parserTax.main(parserTax.java:48)

I am getting the desired 10.00... but then it fails. Is this a bug? I know it has to do something with that special character '%'... I am trying to parse a file for analysis can anyone  help me?

Comment: I understand what the error means... i am wondering why i am still getting the error when the '%' character is there

Comment: little hint: you can replace `if(i == 0 | i == 4 | i == 8 | i == 12 | i == 18 | i == 22 | i == 26 | i == 30 | i == 34){` with `if(i%4 == 0 && i>=0 && i<=34)`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the error is in this line.-

```
String parsedRate = rate[i].substring(0, 5);
```

You're trying to get a subtring from `rate[i]` from position 0 to 5. Have you checked that all `rate` strings have at least 6 characters? Keeping in mind the output, it seems the exception is thrown the second time the `if` condition is true (`i == 4`), so chances are that `rate[4]` contains an empty string.

Comment: the first rate[i] is 10.00% 
second output is showing the parsed rate[i], but then it fails

Comment: hahah wait i think i understand what you mean.... jeez thank you im going to try that

Comment: I'm guessing rate[1] contains 10.00, just 5 characters :)

Comment: System.out.println(rate[i]);
      String parsedRate = rate[i].substring(0, rate[i].indexOf("%"));
      System.out.println(parsedRate);
      double rt = Double.parseDouble(parsedRate);
      if(rt > max){
       max = rt;
      }

Comment: it contains 10.00% 

i parse it and the end result is 

10.00

but then i get an error on the line above the second println

Comment: so it gives me the desire 10.00, but then it gives me an error when it completed the task i wanted it to do... makes no sense

Comment: it has 6 characters... its just acting buggy makes no sense why its failing i think it has something to do with the special character in the string... but idk

Comment: Yes, it seems first loop iteration works fine (i == 0). I think it's failing during the next time the if condition is true (i == 4); my guessing here, given your output, is that `rate[4] == ""`, have you checked that?